# How is the word 'but' used in the famous quote 'What is life but a series of inspired follies?'

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality, word-usage

The full quote attributed to George Bernard Shaw:

> What is life but a series of inspired follies? The difficulty is to find
>   them to do. Never lose a chance: it doesn't come every day.

I understand that the word 'but' could be used as 'only' or 'merely'. However, neither usage seems to fit the above quote. For example "What is life only a series of inspired follies?" doesn't seem grammatically correct. I think this is because it is posed as a question rather than a statement - 'Life is only a series of inspired follies' - here 'only' can be replaced with 'but' to give 'Life is but a series of inspired follies'.

Is there another usage of the word 'but' that I'm missing?

Comment: I implore you: plain 'Bernard Shaw'. He never used the 'George'.

Comment: Many a quotATION attributed to Shaw is spuriously so, many a quotation-monger having the informal rule "when in doubt, attribute to Shaw"; but this is actually genuine, from *Pygmalion.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just meant to put a bit of extra emphasis on "a series of inspired follies". You could read the sentence as "What is life - if not - a series of inspired follies" or "life is nothing - other than - a series of inspired follies".

There are a few similar examples [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/but):

> "Ten to one but the police have got them" (Charlotte M. Yonge).
>
> We would have reached the summit but for the weather.

Also it is a rhetorical question, something nobody has to answer to, as the answer is obvious.

Comment: This is how I understood the quote. Could you please point me to a reference that explains this usage of 'but' for emphasis - specifically as 'if not'?

Comment: Added one I could find.

Answer (score 2):

**I think the closest sense of *but* I can find in the OED is 5b:**

Whilst 5a applies to:

> a. Negative and interrogative sentences containing a comparative
>   (esp. more) were formerly followed by but; they now usually take than,
>   or else the comparative is omitted and but retained; modern idiom
>   preferring sometimes one, sometimes the other.
>
> 1713   Guardian 25 Aug. 2/2   There needed no more but to advance one
>   Step.
>
> 1888   N.E.D. at But,   Mod. There remains no more but to thank you
>   for your courteous attention.

5b relates to:

> b. **So with similar sentences containing other, otherwise, else; in
>   which but is still sometimes retained, esp. after else, as ‘Who else
>   but he?’**
>
> 1589   G. Puttenham Arte Eng. Poesie iii. xix. 164   What els is man
>   but his minde?
>
> 1611   M. Smith in Bible (King James)  Transl. Pref. 1   For none
>   other fault but for seeking to reduce their Countrey-men to good
>   order.
>
> > 1689   R. Milward Selden's Table-talk 41   Pleasure is nothing else
> >     but the intermission of pain.
>
> 1713   Guardian 25 Aug. 2/2   Had no other Fault, but that of being
>   too Short.
>
> 1888   N.E.D. at But,   Mod. It is nothing else but laziness!

Earlier examples date from year 971.

**In the example you gave in the question the sense of *else* is implied. *What (else) is life but a series of inspired follies***?

So it is a use of *but* which has been around since before the Norman Conquest and was alive and well in Saxon England.

Comment: I think OED C.I.7.a might be the better fit: *"elliptically:* Any but, aught but, anything else than, other than, otherwise than. (Often after *ever, never.)"* The general sense C.I is  "In a simple sentence; introducing a word or phrase (rarely a clause) which is excepted from the general statement: Without, with the exception of, except, save."

Comment: @BrianDonovan  I think my choice of 5b was influenced by the interrogative as in *Who else but me*, and also the possibilities for including *else*. But I agree that 7a seems also to fit.